# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address') when trying to access state objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a shipping screen where users that logged in can fill the form for their shipping info, but I get an error in initial state of useState where shippingAddress object seems to have no access to address, postalCode, city, and country objects thus make the ShippingScreen page not rendering.

ShippingScreen.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Form,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  FormGroup,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import FormContainer from "../components/FormContainer";
import { saveShippingAddress } from "../actions/cartActions";

const ShippingScreen = () => {
  const history = useNavigate();
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { shippingAddress } = cart;
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(shippingAddress.address || "");
  const [city, setCity] = useState(shippingAddress.city || "");
  const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState(
    shippingAddress.postalCode || ""
  );
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(shippingAddress.country || "");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(saveShippingAddress({ address, city, postalCode, country }));
    history("/payment");
  };
  return (
    <FormContainer>
      <h1>Shipping</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <FormGroup controlId="address">
          <FormLabel>Address</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter address"
            value={address}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          ></FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="city">
          <FormLabel>City</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter city"
            value={city}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
          ></FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="postalCode">
          <FormLabel>Address</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter postal code"
            value={postalCode}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
          ></FormControl>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup controlId="country">
          <FormLabel>Address</FormLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter country"
            value={country}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
          ></FormControl>
        </FormGroup>

        <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
          Continue
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </FormContainer>
  );
};

export default ShippingScreen;
```

If it helps, these are also the reducers, actions, and store files that used.

cartReducers.js

```
import {
  CART_ADD_ITEM,
  CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
  CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
} from "../constants/cartConstants";

export const cartReducer = (
  state = { cartItems: [], shippingAddress: {} },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item = action.payload;

      const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);

      if (existItem) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
            x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
        };
      }
    case CART_REMOVE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(
          (x) => x.product.id !== action.payload.id
        ),
      };
    case CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        shippingAddress: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

cartActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  CART_ADD_ITEM,
  CART_ADD_ITEM_ERROR,
  CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
  CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
} from "../constants/cartConstants";

export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: {
        product: data._id,
        name: data.name,
        image: data.image,
        price: data.price,
        countInStock: data.countInStock,
        qty,
      },
    });

    localStorage.setItem(
      "cartItems",
      JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems)
    );
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM_ERROR,
      payload: error,
    });
  }
};

export const removeFromCart = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
    payload: id,
  });

  localStorage.removeItem(
    "cartItems",
    JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems)
  );
};

export const saveShippingAddress = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
    payload: data,
  });

  localStorage.setItem("shippingAddress", JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  productListReducer,
  productDetailsReducer,
} from "./reducers/productReducers";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/cartReducers";
import {
  userLoginReducer,
  userRegisterReducer,
  userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfileReducer,
} from "./reducers/userReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
  userRegister: userRegisterReducer,
  userDetails: userDetailsReducer,
  userUpdateProfile: userUpdateProfileReducer,
});

const cartItemsFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];
const userInfoFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))
  : null;
const shippingAddressFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("shippingAddress")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shippingAddress"))
  : {};

const initialState = {
  cart: {
    cartItems: cartItemsFromLocalStorage,
    shippingAdress: shippingAddressFromLocalStorage,
  },
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromLocalStorage },
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Do you initialize your state properly? Seems like the state is `{ cart: {} }` on first render.

In the `cartReducer` you have a default cart state `state = { cartItems: [], shippingAddress: {} }` but that's only effective after the reducer has run. (Which I guess is after first render? Haven't worked with redux though.)

Comment: yes, cart would the first one to render because the shipping screen is after the user have added products to cart, which is in cart screen, after the shipping screen form is filled, the state would be cartItems and shippingAdress, then it will go to the next step, that would be the payment screen (i haven't added that yet though)

I honestly don't know how to fix this

Comment: Hey John so when you initialize the state for shippingAddress try having the property of address in the store state for example const state = {
shippingAddress: { address: "" }
}

See if the error persists otherwise there are other fixes for this if you dont want to take this approach

Comment: @kodamace in which file do i need to add that line?

Comment: @john_smith it must be in your store state where you have the shippingAddress object

Comment: I found my what causing the error, there's a typo in my store.js, in the initialState, it was shippingAdress instead of shippingAddress